# SQL Server : removing CHAR(13) and CHAR(10) at the end of the variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I wonder if there is any way to remove `CHAR(13)` and `CHAR(10)` at the end of the variable.

I got this :

```
SELECT @TEXT
```

`@Text` is a very long line with a lot of `CHAR(13)` and `CHAR(10)`. I just need to remove it when those chars are at the end of the line.

Is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: when I said: at the end of the line, I mean at the end of the variable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT`:

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(100) = 'ABC' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

SELECT @var = CASE WHEN @var LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
                 THEN LEFT(@var, LEN(@var) - 2)
                 ELSE @var
              END;


 SELECT @var, LEN(@var);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/399443)**</kbd>

Comment: Awesome dude! That is all what I was looking for! Thank you!